# Linux file descriptor table and vmalloc

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I see that the Linux kernel uses `vmalloc` to allocate memory for `fdtable` when it's bigger than a certain threshold. I would like to know when this happens and have some more clear information.

```
static void *alloc_fdmem(size_t size)
{
       /*
       * Very large allocations can stress page reclaim, so fall back to
       * vmalloc() if the allocation size will be considered "large" by the VM.
       */
       if (size <= (PAGE_SIZE << PAGE_ALLOC_COSTLY_ORDER)) {
              void *data = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_NOWARN);
              if (data != NULL)
                     return data;
       }
       return vmalloc(size);
}
```

`alloc_fdmem` is called from `alloc_fdtable` and the last function is called from `expand_fdtable`

I wrote this code to print the size.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PAGE_ALLOC_COSTLY_ORDER 3
#define PAGE_SIZE 4096


int main(){
      printf("\t%d\n", PAGE_SIZE << PAGE_ALLOC_COSTLY_ORDER);
}
```

Output

```
 ./printo
  32768
```

So, how many files does it take for the kernel to switch to using `vmalloc` to allocate `fdtable`?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: linux-3.11.1/fs/file.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So PAGE_SIZE << PAGE_ALLOC_COSTLY_ORDER is 32768

This is called like:

```
  data = alloc_fdmem(nr * sizeof(struct file *));
```

i.e. it's used to store struct file pointers.

If your pointers are 4 bytes, it happens when your have 32768/4 = 8192 open files, if your pointers are 8 bytes, it happens at 4096 open files.

Comment: Reading from the above code, which size are given to alloc_fdmem function?

Comment: Do you mean `nr * sizeof(struct file *)` ? nr is the number of file pointers that is to be allocated, this will correspond to the number of file descriptors. So the rest surely is simple math ? If you're on a 32 bit machine so pointers are 4 bytes, you get e.g. 32768 when nr is 8192

Comment: yes i mean "nr * sizeof(struct file *)" so with 8193 file descriptor in the fdtb, linux starts to use vmalloc, tell me if you understood well

Comment: Yes, that's right, and half that if you're on a 64 bit machine